# React-native test cases fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, testcase

I'm trying to write some test cases of a simple react-native app, but my test case always fails with an error which apparently cannot find `UIManager.createView`

### Component

```
class LiveTab extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        ...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={ ... }
                renderRow={ ... }
                />
        );
    }
}

LiveTab.propTypes = { ... };

export default LiveTab;
```

### Test case

```
...
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('LiveTab renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <LiveTab ... />
    );
});
```

### Error

> FAIL  **tests**/components/LiveTab.js (14.766s)   ● LiveTab renders
>   correctly
>
> TypeError: UIManager.createView is not a function
>
> at Constructor.mountComponent (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/native/ReactNativeBase
>   Component.js:201:11)
>
> at Object.mountComponent
>   (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
>         at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactCompositeCompon
>   ent.js:371:34)
>         at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.j
>   s:258:21)
>         at Object.mountComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
>         at ReactTestComponent.mountChildren (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:238:44)
>         at ReactTestComponent.mountComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactTestRenderer.js:62:10)
>         at Object.mountComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
>         at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactCompositeCompon
>   ent.js:371:34)
>         at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.j
>   s:258:21)

I am not able to figure out what the problem is in such a simple component.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error because one of the modules I was importing into my component was not getting transformed by babel, so it needed to be whitelisted in package.json

See example:

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#transformignorepatterns-customization